# this.setState is not a function - Firebase get document error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm newbie at React.
My project simply allows more than one person to listen to music simultaneously. I managed to make an api connection over Spotify, but I keep the information of the room on the firebase. Therefore, I need to get the room's founder, that is, roomAdminMail information, from firebase. When I try to retrieve room information like I did on Homepage, I get an error like this.

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
    Grid,
    Typography,
    Card,
    IconButton,
    LinearProgress,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
import PlayArrowIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow";
import PauseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Pause";
import SkipNextIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SkipNext";
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SkipPrevious';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {GridItem} from '@chakra-ui/react';




const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();

//const Player = props =>
class Player extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams();
   
    
    this.state = {
      logeedIn : params.access_token ? true : false,
      currentStatus: false,
      roomAdminMail: "",
      roomName: "",
      roomInfo: "",
      nowPlaying: {
        artist_name : 'Not Checked',
        song_name: 'Not Checked',
        image: ''
      }
    }

    if(params.access_token){
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token)
    }
  }


  getHashParams() {
   var hashParams = {};
   var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
       q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
   }
   return hashParams;
 }
 getNowPlaying(){
  spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack()
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      nowPlaying: {
        artist_name: response.item.artists[0].name,
        song_name: response.item.name,
        image: response.item.album.images[0].url
      }
    })
  })
}


getRoomCollection(){
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("rooms").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        this.setState(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          roomAdminMail: doc.data().roomAdminMail,
          roomName: doc.data().roomName,
          roomInfo: doc.data().roomInfo
        })));
      })

    }


componentDidMount(){
    this.getNowPlaying();
    this.getRoomCollection();
    
    

}


  
    render() {
      
      return (
        <GridItem
        colStart={[1, null, null, 2, null, null]}
        colSpan={[3, null, null, 1, null, null]}
        p={6}
      >
        <a href='http://localhost:8888'>
        <button>Login With Spotify</button>
        </a>
        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
            Room Admin: {this.state.roomAdminMail}
        </Typography>

        
       
      <Card item align="center">
        <Grid container alignItems="center">
          <Grid item align="center" xs={12} className="now-playing__img">
          <img src={this.state.nowPlaying.image} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item align="center" xs={8}>
          <Typography item align="center" component="h5" variant="h5">
          {this.state.nowPlaying.song_name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography item align="center" color="textSecondary" variant="subtitle1">
              {this.state.nowPlaying.artist_name}
            </Typography>
            <div>
            <IconButton
                onClick={() => { spotifyWebApi.skipToPrevious();
                    {this.getNowPlaying()}
                }}
              >
                <SkipPreviousIcon /> 
              </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                onClick={() => { spotifyWebApi.play();
                    {this.getNowPlaying()}
                }}
              >
                <PlayArrowIcon /> 
              </IconButton>
               
            <IconButton
                onClick={() => { spotifyWebApi.pause();
                    {this.getNowPlaying()}
                }}
              >
                <PauseIcon /> 
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton onClick={() => spotifyWebApi.skipToNext()}>
                {this.getNowPlaying()}
                <SkipNextIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>

          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        
      </Card>
      </GridItem>

 
  );
}
}

export default Player;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this` context to the function or use an arrow function.

Binding this:

```js
constructor(){
    this.getRoomCollection = this.getRoomCollection.bind(this);
    this.getNowPlaying = this.getNowPlaying.bind(this);
  }
```

Using arrow function:

> Just make the function an arrow function

```js
getRoomCollection = () => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("rooms").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        this.setState(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          roomAdminMail: doc.data().roomAdminMail,
          roomName: doc.data().roomName,
          roomInfo: doc.data().roomInfo
        })));
      })

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work for me. Although I do the same as here, I am getting an error; TypeError: this.setState is not a function. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you bind both `getNowPlaying` and `getRoomCollection` with this? @MertÖzler

Comment: Yes I did but this is not solving my problem. It's something like this, I'm stuck... https://i.resmim.net/i/sameproblem.png

Comment: Ohhh., I get it you need to make the callback and arrow function. And then you're good to go

Comment: I've updated the code. let me know if this works for you @MertÖzler

Comment: Yes it works but this did not solve my problem. As I am asking, it aims to navigate one by one by iterating all docs, but what I want to do now is for a particular room, namely; Accessing the information of a room coded 1XoıqSxp. Only the information of this room is enough, how can I do this?